# Formula error then message box

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spread sheet and in column N1:N7, N8:N1, N17:N24, N26:N33, N28:N35 and N36:43 has vlookup formula which bring the result from  sheet1, is this possible that if error (Vlookup not find the result) message box pops up, " Please add new product and specification in Product Sheet1" for user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this without having the VLOOKUP handled by VBA (don't see why you wouldn't)

Try something like this in the ThisWorkbook module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
dim rng as Range
application.ScreenUpdating = False

set ws = ActiveSheet

with ws
    NoRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").end(xlUp).Row
    set rng = Range(.Cells(1, "N"), .Cells(NoRow, "N"))
end with

If Not Intersect(rng, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
for each cell in rng.cells
     if cell.value = "#N/A" Then
         cell.select
         Msgbox "Please add new product and specification in Product Sheet1 for selected cell"
     end if
next cell
end if
application.screenupdating = True
end Sub
```

Failing that you could handle the VLOOKUP function in VBA which would get you better results

Just to reiterate - do this entirely in VBA

Comment: Thanks Tom, I don't know much about VBA, when I try the above code nothing is happening, do I have to give range? As I mention above.

Comment: Where have you put the code? Could you elaborate more on what you're trying to do/What you worksheet is looking like and I might be able to give you a much better answer (What I've put above shouldn't really be done, but am trying to work with what you've got already)

Comment: I have 9 sheets in work book 7 sheets for the day of week (all 7 sheets are same format) 8 sheets has summary and sheet 1 has product and its description. In daily sheet user enter production data, In column "N"  I have vlookup formula which bring the Product Yield from Sheet 1, sometime we produce new product and user forget to add in Sheet 1 and Vlookup formula give me #N/A error which cause all other formula not to work and boss got angry, what I want is a little reminder, if there is error in column "N" ranges as mention earlier, then a message box.

Comment: Ok, don't think I can really do anything else without more information/seeing it. I've updated my original code. Try putting that in the 'ThisWorkbook' module then changing one of the values so the vlookup will fail

Comment: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("N").UsedRange  "Run Time error 438"

Comment: Updated again - Give that a try (Sorry not on a computer with Excel currently)